# Anime with a female main character who fought demons and a big monster

Tags: story-identification, anime

Fairly certain its 2020 or newer, though I do not remember much.

I wanna say the lead was a female. There was like a demon group or something. Some big monster creature was eating people in a kingdom and destroying things. She fought it and almost lost and then snapped out and blew it up and a hole in the town or something.

I think there was a dude in it as well who was like a lone swordsman who is fighting a demon clan.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember where you saw it?

Comment: Pretty sure on what was at the time VRV.  However, that has gone through some iterations since then.